# What were the laws in classical physics that led to prediction that black body will emit infinite energy at high radiation and how?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, frequency, singularities

I have tried to search a lot about the laws that predicted this behaviour of black body. But haven't really found out. And the ones I found like equipartition theorem, i find them contradicting with classical physics itself. How exactly it was predicted that with increase in temperature, there would be increase in intensity of radiation at each frequency.

Comment: Very similar question: [Why using a sum instead of an integral solves the Ultraviolet catastrophe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/717843/)

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html

Answer (score 1):

The concept of equipartition of energy is a supposition that must be granted in order to make any progress.

Conversely, to not grant equipartition of energy means you are bogged down without recourse.

In the past the physics community has granted the equipartition of energy concept, and in the realm of classical physics no counterexamples have been encountered.

So: as far as we can tell the equipartition of energy concept is reliable.

You write: "[...] I find them contradicting with classical physics itself" The only way the members of this forum can address your issue is if you specify what it is that you regard as contradicting classical physics itself.

Comment: Equipartition theorem states that the energy of each frequency in the emitted radiation by the black body will be same, but at the same time, classical physics states that higher the frequency, the higher the energy. These just contradict each other. One says every frequency have same amount of energy, other says the energy varies depending on the frequency.